# Showing that a fixed-point method converges for any positive starting point

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}(x + \frac{3}{x})$ and consider it known that $\sqrt{3}$ is a fixed-point. I have to show that any initial $x_0 > 0$ will converge to the said fixed-point. So far my material has only presented the fixed-point theorem, which states that if a continuously differentiable $f$ is such that $|f'(x)| < 1, \forall x \in [a, b]$, for some interval $[a, b]$, then the iteration will converge to the fixed point.

Since $f'(x) = \frac{1}{2}(1 - \frac{3}{x^2})$, any $x_0 \in (\sqrt{3}, \infty)$ will do. From $|f'(x)| < 1 \Longleftrightarrow -1 < \frac{1}{2}(1 - \frac{3}{x^2}) < 1 \Longleftrightarrow -3 < -\frac{3}{x^2} < 1$ we can deduce that $x$ has to be $x > 1$ or $x < -1$. But how can we extend add the interval $(0, 1]$ for $x_0$?

Comment: @JohnOmielan I had confused myself with my own notes. The function is fixed now as $f$should be $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}(x + \frac{3}{x})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above he condition you need is $x_0^{2} >1$.

Let $x_1=f(x_0)$. Then $x_1 >1$: $x_0+\frac  3 {x_0} >2$ since $(x_0-1)^{2}+2 >0$. Now apply the fixed point theorem you know for the interval $[1,\infty)$ with the starting point $x_1$ to conclude that there exists $x \in [1,\infty)$ with  $f(x)=x$. (For this proof you only need $x_0>0$).

Comment: Unfortunately not. My issue is is that we know the absolute value of the derivative is less than one when $x > 1$ or $x < -1$. All of the fixed-point theorems I have seen are of the form "if $x_0$ is in this interval, then $f$ will converge. But with any $x_0 > 0$, $x_0$ might not be in the desired interval.

Comment: @EpsilonAway I have added some details. I hope it is clear now.